# Closure expression does not necessarily retain the state of the function

Tags: swift, function, closures

```
func makeIncrementerI(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int { //Closure 
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}

//No side effect 
func makeIncrementerII(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0 // you'll get warning: `Variable 'runningTotal' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant`
    return {runningTotal + amount} //Closure expression
}
```

The nested function inside `makeIncrementerI(forIncrement:) -> ()-> Int` is a closure, because it is "closing over" the local variable `runningTotal`. Therefore, the terminal will prints `1 2 3` when the following call is executed:

```
let foo = makeIncrementerI(forIncrement: 1)
for _ in 1...3 { print(foo()) } // print: 1 2 3
```

The nested function inside `makeIncrementerII(forIncrement:) -> ()-> Int` is a function written in closure expression. It is not a closure, therefore, the following call will present triple 1 in the terminal:

```
let foo = makeIncrementerII(forIncrement: 1)
for _ in 1...3 { print(foo()) } // print: 1 1 1
```

**Note**

function can be declared with `func` keyword or by using a shorthand closure expression syntax `{}`. Closure expression doesn't mean the function is a closure.

**Question**

1. Why return `{runningTotal + amount}` in the second function is not a closure?
2. How to create the closure in the closure expressing, a.k.a transform the `func` keyworded closure of the first function into the closure expressed closure?

Comment: `{runningTotal + amount}` in the second function *is* a closure.

Comment: @MartinR The closure does not hold the state of the function, it gives me triple 1 when I calling the function 3 times. I thought closure is a function  can do "Closing over"

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Both runningTotal and amount in the second example are *constants*, and their sum is one. What result did you expect?

Comment: I've tested then by `var`, still triple 1, I know why I did this, the compiler told me this yellow warning message `Variable 'runningTotal' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant`  I just double click to accept the change.

Comment: The closure never changes the value of `runningTotal` in example #2. Again: What result did you expect?

Comment: I expect changing the result of the `runingTotal` by a closure

Comment: The first closure changes the value with `runningTotal += amount`, the second closure does no such thing. Your problem is unclear to me :)

Comment: I think the problem triggered me to asked this question is I'm confused by the closure concept, I'm reading Advanced Swift by Chris Eidhof etc. In Page 21, it claims that: `Function defined within an outer scope, but passed out from it can "capture" local variables ..... This behavior is called "closing over" variables, and functions that do this are called closures. ` This confused me, like what you said the second closure does not change the value but it also "closing over" this unchanged value, so it is also a closure, I hope I get the point this time :)